# How to add a registered user to the User model (within Authentication and authorization section) in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**A newbie here. This is a Django related question.**

How can I save a newly registered user to the User Model (auth.model)? Currently, the only account which is seen inside the admin panel -- under Users (Authentication and Authorization section) is the superuser (aka me).

I am using DRF (Rest framework) in order to register a user and not an HTML form.

**models.py:**

```
class Register(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py:**

```
class RegisterView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = RegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response("Thank you for registering", status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Register

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Register
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

When registering a new user via POSTMAN, the data is saved within the Register model (which is fine) but my issue is that it's not seen within the Users model.

Any feedback is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand why you have created a separate Register model. It doesn't have anything that doesn't already exist on User. You should remove it.

Comment: But without the Register model, how can I register new users? Can you elaborate on your statement, please?

Comment: What? You have the User model. That is how you register users. Why would you need a separate Register model? What is gained by storing the username/email/password in two separate db tables?

Comment: Oh. I am planning to create an API out of this model. How would you create an API using just the User Model? What changes should I make to my views.py module then?

Comment: The same way as you would for any other model, by creating a serializer that references User.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Actually, my intention is to create a user who can have access to the JWT tokens. Currently, only the superuser (aka me) only has access. But, I want this to be made possible with any user who registers. How can that be made possible? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: you should handle it by permissions on the view which is appropriate to tokens.